# Doing joins with Fluent in a Vapor application

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm struggling to figure out how to join my two tables together using fluent.  In essence I want to run this SQL command:

```sql
SELECT p.name, o.amount, o.amount * p.amount total
FROM "OrderPoints" o 
INNER JOIN "Points" p ON o.points_id = p.id 
WHERE order_id = 10831
```

I've got my two models setup like so:

```swift
final class OrderPoint: Codable, PostgreSQLModel, Content, Migration {
    var id: Int? = nil
    var orderID: Order.ID
    var pointID: Point.ID
    var amount: Double = 0

    var point: Parent<OrderPoint, Point> {
        return parent(\.pointID)
    }
}

final class Point: Codable, PostgreSQLModel, Content, Migration {
    var id: Int? = nil
    var name: String
    var abbrev: String
    var amount: Double
}
```

So now in my controller I loop over all of the orders that I care about:

```swift
// SELECT * FROM orders WHERE "month" = '2018-05-01'
let orders = try Order.query(on: req).filter(\Order.month == month).all()

return orders.flatMap(to: View.self) { orders in
    let content = try orders.map { (order) -> OrderIndexContent in
        let values = try order.orderPoints.query(on: req).all()
```

and I think that gets me all the items from `order_points` for the current ID, but I am just not seeing how to join it with the `Points` model so that I can do the rest of the query (i.e. get the multiplied amount and the point name)

[image]

- An `Order` has multiple `OrderPoint` items.
- An `OrderPoint` has a *single* `Point` item.
- A `Point` could point to many `OrderPoint` items.

So in the way I think fluent refers to things, `OrderPoints` is *not* a pivot, as it's not a many to many.

## This can't be right.

The following seems to be working, but there's no way this is the "right" way to do it as this would be massive amounts of extra SQL calls, right?

```swift
_ = try! order.orderPoints
              .query(on: req)
              .all()
              .map(to: Void.self) { pointsForOrder in
                  pointsForOrder.forEach { orderPoint in
                      _ = try! orderPoint.point.get(on: req).map(to: Void.self) {
                          print("\(order.id!) \(order.name) \($0.abbrev) \(orderPoint.pointID) = \(orderPoint.amount) = \($0.amount * orderPoint.amount)")
                      }
                  }
          }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to retrieve all the `Point`s referenced in the `OrderPoint`s from an `Order` you would have to query `Point` and join `OrderPoint` on it. Then you can add a filter on `OrderPoint` filtering the order you want to query.

This would result in the following Fluent query:

```
Point.query(on: req)
    .join(field: \OrderPoint.pointID)
    .filter(OrderPoint.self, \OrderPoint.orderID == order.id!)
    .all()
```

This query would however only return an array of `Point`s, so you would miss the information from `OrderPoint` as you pointed out in our discussion on Discord we would also have to decode `OrderPoint`, luckily Fluent has a nice method for this: `.alsoDecode`. So the final query would look like this:

```
Point.query(on: req)
    .join(field: \OrderPoint.pointID)
    .filter(OrderPoint.self, \OrderPoint.orderID == order.id!)
    .alsoDecode(OrderPoint.self)
    .all()
```

This would return a tuple containing both `Point` and `OrderPoint`

Comment: Note this has changed in more recent versions of Fluent: https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/query/#join and https://github.com/vapor/fluent/issues/759